# Getting garbage data when not projecting _id mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

Below given in my query to generate organization hierarchy,

```
db.org.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                parent: "$parent",
                level: "$level"
            },
            level_data: {$push:{name: "$name", id: "$_id"}}
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$_id.level",
            data: {$push: {parent: "$_id.parent", nodes: "$level_data"}}
        }
    },
    {
        $sort:{
            _id: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            //_id: 0,
            level: "$_id",
            data: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

My response:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "data" : [
        {
            "parent" : "null",
            "nodes" : [
                {
                    "name" : "MBC",
                    "id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9feb6")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "level" : 1
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "data" : [
        {
            "parent" : "MBC",
            "nodes" : [
                {
                    "name" : "National",
                    "id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9feb7")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "level" : 2
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "data" : [
        {
            "parent" : "National",
            "nodes" : [
                {
                    "name" : "QUEBEC/MARITIMES",
                    "id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9febd")
                },
                {
                    "name" : "PRAIRIES",
                    "id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9febc")
                },
                {
                    "name" : "ONTARIO",
                    "id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9febb")
                },
                {
                    "name" : "GTA",
                    "id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9feba")
                },
                {
                    "name" : "GMA",
                    "id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9feb9")
                },
                {
                    "name" : "BRITISH COLUMBIA",
                    "id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9feb8")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "level" : 3
}
```

My Response when I un-comment _id:0 in last project stage

```
/* 1 */
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "parent" : "null",
            "nodes" : [
                {
                    "name" : "MBC",
                    "id" : {
                        "data" : "\u0016\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007obj\u0000\\u#ï¢ò\u00161\u0014ùþ¶\u0000"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "level" : {
        "data" : "\u0012\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001obj\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000ð?\u0000"
    }
},

/* 2 */
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "parent" : "MBC",
            "nodes" : [
                {
                    "name" : "National",
                    "id" : {
                        "data" : "\u0016\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007obj\u0000\\u#ï¢ò\u00161\u0014ùþ·\u0000"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "level" : {
        "data" : "\u0012\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001obj\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000@\u0000"
    }
},

/* 3 */
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "parent" : "National",
            "nodes" : [
                {
                    "name" : "QUEBEC/MARITIMES",
                    "id" : {
                        "data" : "\u0016\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007obj\u0000\\u#ï¢ò\u00161\u0014ùþ½\u0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name" : "PRAIRIES",
                    "id" : {
                        "data" : "\u0016\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007obj\u0000\\u#ï¢ò\u00161\u0014ùþ¼\u0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name" : "ONTARIO",
                    "id" : {
                        "data" : "\u0016\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007obj\u0000\\u#ï¢ò\u00161\u0014ùþ»\u0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name" : "GTA",
                    "id" : {
                        "data" : "\u0016\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007obj\u0000\\u#ï¢ò\u00161\u0014ùþº\u0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name" : "GMA",
                    "id" : {
                        "data" : "\u0016\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007obj\u0000\\u#ï¢ò\u00161\u0014ùþ¹\u0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name" : "BRITISH COLUMBIA",
                    "id" : {
                        "data" : "\u0016\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007obj\u0000\\u#ï¢ò\u00161\u0014ùþ¸\u0000"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "level" : {
        "data" : "\u0012\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001obj\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\b@\u0000"
    }
}
```

Below given is the sample of my document structure:

```
/* 1 createdAt:2/26/2019, 4:33:03 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9fefe"),
    "name" : "813",
    "parent" : "QUEBEC/MARITIMES",
    "level" : 4
},

/* 2 createdAt:2/26/2019, 4:33:03 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9fefd"),
    "name" : "551",
    "parent" : "QUEBEC/MARITIMES",
    "level" : 4
},

/* 3 createdAt:2/26/2019, 4:33:03 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9fefc"),
    "name" : "550",
    "parent" : "QUEBEC/MARITIMES",
    "level" : 4
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9feba"),
    "name" : "GTA",
    "parent" : "National",
    "level" : 3
},

/* 70 createdAt:2/26/2019, 4:33:03 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9feb9"),
    "name" : "GMA",
    "parent" : "National",
    "level" : 3
},

/* 71 createdAt:2/26/2019, 4:33:03 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9feb8"),
    "name" : "BRITISH COLUMBIA",
    "parent" : "National",
    "level" : 3
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9feb7"),
    "name" : "National",
    "parent" : "MBC",
    "level" : 2
},

/* 73 createdAt:2/26/2019, 4:33:03 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7523efa2f2163114f9feb6"),
    "name" : "MBC",
    "parent" : "null",
    "level" : 1
}
```

As you can see in the last project stage, _id is commented out, its because, when I turn off its projection it corrupts my output. Else every thing is working fine.

> Response and Documents are just for the reference not exact.

Comment: Which version? it works fine with 4.0.6.

Comment: I am using 4.0.6, its working fine when projecting _id but it does not work when not projecting _id. I didn't check it on any other version.

Comment: It must be something with your set up then. https://mongoplayground.net/p/hAAmqfcC27L works on 4.0.8 as well.

Comment: Thanks Alex Blex. It was not the issue of MongoDB server or client. But it was a bug of MongoBooster(GUI) that i am using. Problem is resolved when a ran it on native mongo client and also test on other GUIs like Studio3T.